# Sending a command to Raspberry PI using an Android App

Tags: android, linux, apache

I'm currently working on a small project of simply controlling the lights in my apartment. I have a Raspberry Pi setup to control the lights with a 433 Mhz transmitter. I can send on/off commands to the lights using a "send code  " command through the command line on the PI. I'm looking to create an Android App to do this for me, and I'm looking for a way to make this happen.

The Raspberry Pi is always connected to the internet, so I was thinking about hosting an Apache Webserver on it, and then somehow sending it commands from the app.  Would anyone know how to go about doing this? I have little knowledge about Apache or webservers to begin with, but my basic google searches have pulled up ideas about using http posts.

Would figuring out how to use an HTTP post be the best course of action, or is there an easier way?

Comment: You should be able to handle things this way, but setting up servers can be a little tricky if it is your first go. I would almost recommend setting it up on something like AWS to play around with, somewhere with a friendly UI, getting it to work, and then trying to transfer what you learned in that process to your PI. Just my opinion of course.

Comment: If you google a bit around you will find projects for your raspi which do just that. Installing a webserver and then connecting from a browser in the same network to switch leds on and off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options but probably some Python web framework running on your Raspberry PI will do the job (Twisted, Django or many other).
Python is preinstalled in the PI so it could be the easier choice.

Your Android app will then run HTTP requests (using HttpClient or something more elaborated) to the Python web server that will run in response the bash code.

The real problem comes when you will want to secure your end point (via login or whatever secret sent via Https) to be sure you are the only one switching on/off your lights :)

Comment: Haha for now, I'll let everyone shut my lights on and off, it'll just be a larger test pool!

Do you know where I could start looking to see the basics of getting something like that set up? What some key words to type into google might be

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use an SSH library such as [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to create a simple android app that sends the desired commands to your raspberry pi, on the press of a button. Of course, if you need to learn how to make an android app, have a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) first.

Comment: I was looking into this option as well. Simply create buttons that send the command to the PI over ssh. I've only just begun working with ssh, so quick beginner question. Will I need to have an ssh session open the entire time the app is open, or can I send single commands over ssh without leaving the connection open?

Comment: @Brian5193 You'd just need to create a session every time you want to send a command, send the command, then disconnect.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12005771)

Comment: @Ferrybig I'll provide an MCV snippet later when I get time - would that be enough to improve my answer, or should there be more? I was giving an example (being jsch) of how they could implement the solution I had proposed, rather than saying that they should use it, and so I don't really know what else I should change. 

As for the android app link, that's the documentation for developers new to android, and as such I feel that there is no way to summarise it on here.

Comment: @HarryShipton Including a example of how to use the library to send a command to the other device would make your answer more detailed, and would give the OP an example how the code would look. I recommend you also move the information in your last comment to the answer about creating a session as needed, as this is also useful information